# Google chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m font issues

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, google-font-api

I've updated Google chrome browser recently. I noticed some of the fonts are not rendering correctly. On the other browsers it's seems fine. However this issue only appear in Chrome v32.0.17...76 m.

I've used "Open Sans" & "Novecentowide" Fonts.

The below CSS styles I've used for my HTML heading.

```
CSS
----

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansSemibold';
    src: url('../fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.svg#OpenSansSemibold') format('svg');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansRegular';
    src: url('../fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#OpenSansRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'novecentowide-medium-webfont';
    src: url('../fonts/fonts_main/Novecentowide-m/Novecentowide-Medium-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/fonts_main/Novecentowide-m/Novecentowide-Medium-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/fonts_main/Novecentowide-m/Novecentowide-Medium-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/fonts_main/Novecentowide-m/Novecentowide-Medium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/fonts_main/Novecentowide-m/Novecentowide-Medium-webfont.svg#novecentowide-medium-webfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'novecentowide-normal-webfont';
    src: url('../fonts/fonts_main/Novecentowide-n/Novecentowide-Normal-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/fonts_main/Novecentowide-n/Novecentowide-Normal-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/fonts_main/Novecentowide-n/Novecentowide-Normal-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/fonts_main/Novecentowide-n/Novecentowide-Normal-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/fonts_main/Novecentowide-n/Novecentowide-Normal-webfont.svg#novecentowide-normal-webfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1 { font-family: 'OpenSansRegular'; } 

HTML
---------
<h1> Test on CHrome </h1>
```

However still fonts are not rendering correctly on new version of Chrome Browser. Please help me to solve this issue.

Edit:

**On Chrome**

[image: On chrome]

**On fire fox**

[image: On Fire Fox]

- On Chrome

  -----------**Next Method**-------------------------------------------

**HTML**

```
<h6 class="title1">This is opensans Regular</h6>
<h6 class="title2">This is opensans semibold</h6>
```

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansRegular';
    src: url('/fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#OpenSansRegular') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansSemibold';
    src: url('/fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/fonts_main/open-sans/OpenSans-Semibold-webfont.svg#OpenSansSemibold') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
}


h6.title1 {
    font-family: 'OpenSansRegular';
    font-weight: normal;
}

h6.title2 {
    font-family: 'OpenSansSemibold';;
    font-weight: 600;
}

h6.title1, h6.title2 { color: #54403C; font-size: 1.3em; }
body { font-size: 10px; }
```

Chrome
[image]

Fire Fox
[image]

Comment: What does "not render correctly" entail? Do you have an example? A screenshot?

Comment: Hi RoeIN, Thanks - please see the attached screen shot on the post

Comment: it's reported here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332958

Answer (score 0):

So Chrome is rendering in normal font-weight, and Firefox is bold?

The font you're specifying only has a normal weight. So Chrome is correctly rendering the font, and Firefox has applied a faux bold effect to a non-bold typeface, as its default style for an `h1` is to apply "boldness".

If you want them both normal:

```
h1 { 
    font-family: 'OpenSansRegular'; 
    font-weight: normal; /* tell all browsers not to apply faux bold */
}
```

Or, if you want them both bold, specify the semi-bold face you have:

```
h1 { 
    font-family: 'OpenSansSemibold'; 
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

This is a common pitfall when working with web fonts - always specify a font-weight on elements using them to avoid this.

EDIT

Adding `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;` to the heading styles may help to normalise the rendering between browsers. I'm not sure if it addresses actual character rendering or just uses a different kerning algorithm, but worth a shot. It's difficult for me to test this as I don't have the same issue with this font on Chrome here.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've try your method. However font-weight bold still not rendering perfect in chrome new version. However the old chrome version i never faced issues like that. Please see the code and screen latest shots above.

Comment: I see in your update that it's rendering a bit "quirkily" in chrome. At least the font-weight issue is sorted. I think that's as far as you can go other than bug reporting. I have one other thought that might help - see update above.